# Test if PowerShell script being called with Invoke-Expression?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to tell if a script is being called using Invoke-Expression rather than called directly? I want to do something different, e.g. pause for input, if the script is being called directly but skip that if it is being called from another location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, I would say no.

Instead you should structure the code in such a way that you could inform the code either that it should or should not prompt, like with a `-Prompt` parameter or something.

I can't really give more specific advice without seeing the code or knowing what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I believe the correct Powershellway of doing this is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Also, if you set some variables as mandatory, then launch the script without those parameters from an interactive session, powershell will prompt you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Invoke-Expression the one way I've found is to use Get-PSCallStack.

So for instance, if I have a script called foo1.ps1 into which I put :

```
$CallStack = Get-PSCallStack | select -ExpandProperty Command
$CallStack[($CallStack.count-2)]
```

then create a second script called foo2.ps1 which just contains :

```
Invoke-Expression .\foo1.ps1
```

If I run foo1.ps1 directly at a PS prompt it returns foo1.ps1, if I run foo2.ps1 it returns that script name instead.

Another method I found is using $MyInvocation, but that doesn't seem to work with Invoke-Expression. If you simply call the script with "& .\foo1.ps1" or even just ".\foo1.ps1" it works. With that method if you put the following in foo1.ps1 :

```
if ($MyInvocation.ScriptName -eq "") {Write-Host "Run directly"}
else {Write-Host "Called from " $MyInvocation.ScriptName }
```

It will display either that you've called it directly or return the path to the script (eg foo2.ps1) which called it.